# SSH port forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, portforwarding

I'm using SSH port forwarding to connect to Windows Remote Desktop from my Linux machine, like this:

```
ssh -L 50000:192.0.2.10:3389 user@example.com
rdesktop -f localhost:50000 -u user -p password
```

Now, the first command opens the remote command line on my terminal, so I have to open another terminal to issue the second one. How can I make ssh go on the background so I wouldn't have to open a new terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try ssh with -Nf flags. man ssh for more information.